# How to tell if stocks are in sync?

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means, stocks

In stocks some symbols are closely related. If one goes up, the other goes down, or they rise and fall together. For example, Exxon and BP have similar ups and downs. How can you tell if two stocks have similar trends. Would it involve clustering? What data points would you cluster? Would you cluster multiple sets?

Comment: This question may be better asked in [Cross-Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it involves clustering.

For the input companies collect profit, loss, customer feedbacks, demand of the product, years in business, etc.,